# Understanding Enumerator in List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

The source code of [Enumerator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140) is:

```
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, System.Collections.IEnumerator {
   private List<T> list;
   private int index;
   private int version;
   private T current;
   ...
   public bool MoveNext() {

      List<T> localList = list;  <--------------Q1

      if (version == localList._version && ((uint)index < (uint)localList._size)) {
         current = localList._items[index];
         index++;
         return true;
      }
      return MoveNextRare();
   }

   private bool MoveNextRare() {
      if (version != list._version) {
         ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
      }

      index = list._size + 1;   <-----------------Q2
      current = default(T);
      return false;
   }
   
void System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset() {
      if (version != list._version) {
         ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
      }

      index = 0;
      current = default(T);
   }
   ...
}
```

I have some questions on this iterator pattern:

Q1-Why `MoveNext` method need to define a `localList`, can't it just use the private field `list` directly since `List<T>` is already a reference type, why need to create an alias for it?

Q2- `MoveNextRare` method will invoke when the index is out of range of the last element in the list, so what's the point to increment it, why not just leave it untouched, because when `Reset()` calls, index will be set to 0 anyway?

Comment: #1 Looks like a safety thing with the version & bounds/size protection (remember its an enumerator so if you iterate and delete an item (not in reverse) it throws an exception). #2 I hold a different view, this is correct as you'd write in any typical incremental function. Reset does that job of setting to 0.

Comment: Why do you think that `Reset` will be called?

Comment: @JeremyThompson personally I don't see any reason to introduce the local variable here for version checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question I don't have any answer, maybe it just an relic from some previous implementation, maybe it somehow improves performance (though I would wonder how and why, so my bet is on the first guess). Also in the Core implementation `list` field is marked as [readonly](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L1079).

As for the second one - it has nothing to do with `Reset`, but with `System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current` [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1187):

```
Object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current {
    get {
        if( index == 0 || index == list._size + 1) { // check second comparasion
            ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumOpCantHappen);
    }
    return Current;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it strange that properties `public T Current` and  `Object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current` behaves differently.

Comment: @Magnus yes, a little bit. Also for the case when `MoveNext` returned false the behavior of `Current` is undefined as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.current?view=net-5.0) so I would say that this behavior is kept for non-generic version for the sake of backward compatibility. Also I would say that usually both `Reset` and non-generic `Current` should not be called on the `List<T>` enumerator, cause it is a struct and calling those will require relatively expensive boxing.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for your answers especially for the answer to second question, I didn't even notice that. BTW, what does version for? I saw a lot of code in List, Dictionary that once you add an item, then do `version++`. what's the reason to do this?

Comment: @amjad as Jeremy wrote in the comment to the question - it is used to check that collection has not changed after the iteration has started (i.e. if for example something was added/removed to/from list during iteration the enumerator will throw).

Comment: That is done to preserve correctness/consistency of iteration.